# The new employee

Tags: wordplay, english

Recently, the principal at my school announced that he would be hiring a new staff member. He told us that if we could figure out what he was, and what subject he would be teaching, we would receive a 7(the highest possible grade) in all our courses. The only clues he gave were:

1.

> He is a man

2.

> He is not human

3.

> His species is known as the "rag people", although this is not their true name

4.

> His job will include others like him, but he won't be a janitor.

Since by the end of the school day after he announced the first clues, we have failed to solve it, he has decided to give one final clue that he claims will "make it obvious", and so he's lowering the reward to be that if you have an overall grade below 6, you'll receive a 6 instead.
UPDATE: I received the script of what exactly he said just a little while ago. It reads:

> If he was a man from the Egyptian people, he would be an Egyptian man. Therefore, if he's from the rag people...

---

Note: 99% of the story is just fluff

Comment: i vote to close as too broad

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It's not that broad. The clues only match up well with one thing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: what's that then?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry The answer to the puzzle.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry You said you're voting to close, and yet you actually [voted to leave open](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/24645)?

Comment: i pressed the wrong button

Comment: @Wasiq Shahrukh, I saw your edit, but I am not sure if it is relevant. You say "person". The OP says "not human". Perhaps "what" is appropriate here?

Comment: Do you know the answer to this (ie. is the whole principal thing just fluff) or not?

Comment: @Joe yup I know the answer xP the story is about 90-95% pure fluff, and the rest is some clues I threw in

Comment: @randal'thor; pressed the wrong button again, i'll get it right next time i promiz.

Comment: @randal'thor I edited it .-. if it's still bad, could you guys at least say something, instead of just leaving it closed with no discussion?

Comment: @Saiid I voted to leave open originally, but now I do think it's too broad: i.e. there are too many possibilities which could fit the clues given. I may be wrong, but others seem to agree (there have been no votes to reopen so far).

Comment: @randal'thor What about the last clue I added? I feel like that makes it pretty easy

Comment: @randal'thor so no discussion at all? just permanently on hold?

Comment: @Saiid I'm not sure why you're pinging me about it; I was just one of the five close-voters. If you'd like to make a case for it to be reopened, you can post a question on [meta] about it.

Comment: @randal'thor okay. i did send you a comment before, though, and you didn't answer.

Answer (score 5):

> It's a sheet music with "The Entertainer", and he teaches students to play the piano.
>  1. According to Wikipedia, the song is dedicated to "James Brown and his Mandolin Club", so there's the possibility that the name refers to James Brown, who is male.
>  2. A sheet music isn't human.
>  3. The genre of music is called Ragtime, or Rag.
>  4. There will be many many sheet musics with different songs on them.

Comment: That's quite interesting, although it's not what I'm looking for. Try not to take the clues completely literally, and maybe combine a couple? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Only partly fitting the clues so far, but maybe it's

> A plastic human skeleton (for a biology classroom)

```
He is a man
```

> It has male bone structure

```
He is not human
```

> Its not a real one.

```
His species is known as the "rag people", although this is not their true name
```

> Not sure about this one, but I'm thinking about mummies, which are sometimes skeletons wrapped in rags.

```
His job will include others like him, but he won't be a janitor.
```

> His only job is to hang around in the classroom and being pointed at.

Comment: This is well thought out, also I must say that he is not really 'male', he is a man. ;P

Answer (score 2):

It's Towlie from South Park, he's is undoubtedly not female and also not one-man. Another word for a towel can be a rag. So he is a "rag-man" or a towel-man, he's a towel! And he's not the only one there were others like him, of his "species". They all "worked" for the government at a certain point, sharing the same job as agents. But being a towel they also can't fight their urge to clean up spills and messes when they occur but he is NOT a janitor, he is but a simple towel who happened to love to get high. And it's only weed so why not "hire" him.

Is this answer better?

Comment: lol it doesn't fit everything

Comment: I figured it was wortha shot, my other guess is a ghost.

Answer (score 1):

bit of a stretch, but

> is it Stop-light Reports ?

Third clue : His species is known as the "rag people", although this is not their true name

> RAG stands for Red, Amber, Green
>  signifying signal (The one on the road)
>  and according to what I read they are also used for [project assessments](http://www.ginaabudi.com/what-does-red-amber-and-green-mean-for-your-projects/)

also

> It is report/signal
> so, it is 'male' but not 'human' and definitely not 'janitor'

I know, it can be explained better, but I don't know how,
All in all my suggestion is that "meet your deadlines"

Comment: It is a bit of a stretch, sorry. And as for the first clue, it doesn't work with 'male', it has to be 'man'. :P

Answer (score 0):

Is he perhaps

> a ragdoll in a physics engine - they're "man" shaped but not human, and you typically use a decent number of them.

Another possibility, for much the same reasoning would be

> a crash test dummy

although I can't think why you'd "hire" one of those in a school.

Comment: Hey, stories don't always make sense, okay?

Comment: They do when they're posted as puzzles on PSE ;-)

Comment: lel I've seen some pretty bizarre ones

Answer (score 0):

Possibly is

> a book/manuscript

Or simply

> a mop

1.

> both are or can look like a man OR be a MANuscript

2.

> well they are not human

3.

> Both can be made using Egyptian Papyrus or Cotton

4.

> More than one mop or book/manuscript